# asp.net login controls always work with local sqlserver but only intermittently on hosted server

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web site. I use asp.net login controls generated by the templates and wizards. My  tables such as AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles are in the same db as my data.
When I run my site against a local sqlserver database I can use my login controls to login and and everything works fine. When I moved my site to GoDaddy (I also tried on smarterAsp.net with the same problem), my login control works sometimes. Other times it just ignores me and takes me back to the default page with no error message. If I reset the app pool or make a change to the web.config (which seems to reset the app pool), I can log on again for a few times. In IE it is much worse than chrome. In IE I can rarely log on.

In order to trouble shoot my db connection, I added   to one of my pages so that I could access it without logging in. After I go to that page which accesses the database, THEN if I go to the login page, I can log in. It seems to me that my login controls are not being allowed to access the db, but my listview control on my page is and then once the connection is opened by the sqlDataSource, then the login control can authenticate. I have wasted a week on this!!! Help!
I am using the same connection string both for the SQLDataSources as well as the aspNet authentication.
Here is my web.config. It might be a little bit of a mess because I have been trying all kind of things. I am only using "LocalSqlServer" connection string.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;Initial Catalog=Aveida;Integrated Security=False;User Id=XXXXX; Password=XXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <remove name = "DefaultConnection"/>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;Initial Catalog=Aveida;Integrated Security=False;User Id=XXXXX; Password=XXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="he-IL" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trust level="Full" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <location path="SearchLost.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="member,manager" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Account/Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="manager" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think I solved the problem. (can't pose an answer for a few more hours)
I changed 
  

   <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" />
          </providers>

to just 
   

<sessionState mode="InProc" > 

I got rid of the customProvider (don't know where i got that to begin with) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. (can't pose an answer for a few more hours)
 I changed

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
 <providers> 
<add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" /> 
</providers>
```

to just

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" >
```

I got rid of the customProvider (don't know where i got that to begin with) and it seems to work.